How to implement random children selection using a behavior tree framework that doesn't support it?
How to implement random children selection using a behavior tree framework that doesn't support it? Assuming that I want to select one of three possible actions with equal probability this is the best thing I've managed to come up with is this:

A fallback containing 3 sequences, each but last one with a condition node returning SUCCESS with a certain probability. At the first glance, this approach doesn't seem to be too bad, but if you consider how having more actions, potentially with different probabilities would quickly turn maintaining such tree into a nightmare. Do you have any other ideas for implementing something like this?
I'm using BehaviourTree.CPP.

I can see quite a few projects when I search for BehaviourTree.CPP — want to link to the specific one you're using? If you have the source code, would it be feasible to edit it to add your own "randomly select among children" node?

@DMGregory this is the library that I'm using: link. Editing the source code of it isn't something that I'd like to do. fortunately after a bit more research I've noticed something that could help me in the docs: link it seems like a sequence of preconditions would do the trick

Once you've verified that works, want to document your solution as an answer below to help the next person struggling with something similar?

Are you sure you can't create new behaviours in your own source and tell BT.cpp that these exist?

My solution in C like code:
Root_node or anytime before evaluation of next level:
int r = (int)(srand() * 3); // Use include <random> or "random.h" or other rng here

Then set the selection condition for each child node based on the value of the r variable:
Node one:
if (r==0){ //... }
Node two:
if (r==1){ //... }
Node three:
if (r==2){ //... }
